# Ajax PostBack: Read data from Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I read the data from my controller in my ajax postback?

I have a Razor form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDocument", "Pages", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createDocumentForm" }))
{
   ....
}
```

And I catch the Submit action in JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#createDocumentForm").submit(
            function () {
                showWaitMode();
                $.ajax({
                    data: ("#createDocumentForm").serialize, 
                    success: (e) => {
                        console.log(e);
                    },
                    error: (errorResponse) => {
                        alert(errorResponse)
                    }
                })
                return false;
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

In my controller I hit this method:

```
public ActionResult CreateDocument(NotatFletModel model)
{
    var reuslt = new
    {
        Staus = true,
        GoDocumentId = model.ContactId.ToString(),
        ErrorMessage = model.DocumentKindId,
    };

    return Json(reuslt);
}
```

But in my Ajax success function I would like to get the data from my contorller. I expected it to be in my parameter e but it's not

So in short: How do I do an Ajax post and read the data posted back from the controller

Comment: Try chaining the success function to following: `success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            console.log(data);
    }`

Comment: `data: ("#createDocumentForm").serialize()` you forgot the parentheses of `serialize` method, so you're assigning the method `serialize` to `data` while you should assign *the returned value* of `serialize` method to `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout my code for Form Post using ajax

Html :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateDocument", "Pages", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createDocumentForm" }))
{
....
}
```

Jquery :

```
 $("#createDocumentForm").submit(
        function (e) {
            showWaitMode();
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data); // show response 
                },
                error: (errorResponse) => {
                    alert(errorResponse)
                }
            })
            return false;
        }
    );
```

Controller :

```
 //You can Use FormCollection also to get data
 //public ActionResult CreateDocument(FormCollection fc) {
 [HttpPost]     
 public ActionResult CreateDocument(NotatFletModel model) {
 //your logic
 return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```